# How to weaponize ball lightning

Tags: weapons

### Desired Product:

- A railgun that allows me to shoot ball lightings  at my enemies,  like a god from greek myth
- At impact, the ball lightning violently explodes ([And that wasn't even a direct hit!](https://youtu.be/MNJRPOltifI?t=16))
  [image]
  *Hey, what's up guys, it's scarce here.* (artistic illustration of a ball lightning)

---

### Additional Info:

- Please use what the [direct measurements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_lightning#Direct_measurements_of_natural_ball_lightning) have found out about the ball
  lightning.
- Let's just say, that the energy requirements can be handwaved.

More details:

> Some have speculated that ball lightning is a plasma ball, but that theory has been dismissed because a "hot globe of plasma should rise like a hot-air balloon" and that is not what ball lightning does.

**Who cares? It responds strongly to magnetic fields, lasts longer and is hot enough, that's all we need.**

Note:
We don't exactly know how ball lightnings are created, but the most likely theory is:

> When lightning strikes the ground, the minerals are broken down into tiny particles of silicon and its compounds with oxygen and carbon. The tiny charged particles link up into chains, which go on to form filamentary networks. These cluster together in a light fluffy ball, which is borne aloft by air currents. There, it hovers as ball lightning, or a burning orb of fluffy silicon emitting the energy absorbed from the lightning in form of heat and light, until the phenomenon burns itself out.

*This theory is supported by the direct measurements of a ball lightning.*
[source](http://skepdic.com/balllightning.html)

---

### Question:

**How can I design a railgun to shoot ball lightning?**

---

### Note

Based on what I've read a weapon like this would be [terrifying](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/22247).

### [Related.](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/72943/sci-fi-science-physics-of-impossibru-how-the-ball-lightning-destroyed-the-ali)

Comment: ***Is there any flaw in this concept, that can ruin my idea?*** <- what concept? Railguns exist, albeit in prototype form. But balls of lightning? What the heck are those supposed to be? And no, I'm not going to watch the video attached. Please explain whatever concept it is you're trying to get feedback on.

Comment: I have re-worded to make this more like an actual question. @Secespitus This is not a duplicate because this is an actual question and is not 'unclear what he is asking' like the last one :)

Comment: @AndreiROM Ok, it's just an example of an often overlooked possible effect of a plasma cannon. How'd you never heard about ball lightning? (google is your BEST friend in finding new information)

Comment: @RedactedRedacted - we shouldn't have to google anything, or access external links to understand the basic premise of your question. Maybe you should have included screenshots and a brief description that you're talking about the effects of firing plasma, etc. Sites can move, links change, plus some of us are answering from work and can't research your topic, or watch videos. Your question lacks any real context without following those links, and so if those move then your question becomes very difficult to understand for future users.

Comment: @AndreiROM Is it ok now?

Comment: I understand what you're asking now. Before I actually thought that you already had a specific method of generating a ball of lightning in mind. Now I understand that you're asking us how one might be generated and fired at an enemy. This is answerable (with some hand-waving), and - IMO - in scope. Could still use some editing (again, IMO), but yea, it's way better.

Comment: I have seen some success creating ball lightning by striking an arc welder against a block of silicon, but other than some little pretty orbs dancing across the floor, not too useful.

Comment: @Samwise the natural one that was measured was composed of many other stuff, check it for yourself, although it's true that it was 5 meters in diameter and existed for one second (which is orders of magnitudes greater than in the case of most plasmas).

Answer (score 4):

**You fire it once, then it melts.**

Let's suppose you manage to make your ball lightning rail gun (BLRG) out of this recently [discovered substance](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/speaking-of-science/wp/2015/07/28/behold-a-new-record-for-the-worlds-highest-melting-point/?utm_term=.78af8d3881ce), a combination of hafnium, nitrogen and carbon, expected to have a melting point of about 4400 kelvin.  Or if that doesn't work, the other material mentioned in that article, whose melting point is 4200 kelvin.

Compare that to a quote in your own Wikipedia link, which shows a lower bound for the temperature of ball lightning at 15000 kelvin:

> From the spectrum, the temperature of the ball lightning was assessed as being lower than the temperature of the parent lightning (<15,000–30,000 K..."

You propose to toss a mass of plasma at 15000 kelvin down the barrel of a BLRG that melts at no more than 4400 kelvin.  Granted, the plasma won't be in contact with BLRG for long, so it probably won't melt completely to nothing.  However, I suspect the damage will render this a one-and-done weapon.  Unfortunately, I don't think this passes the reality-check test.

Comment: Can I confine the plasma right after it's creation, then hurl it at my enemies? Like tokamaks?

Comment: Correction: like how tokamaks confine the hotter than the sun plasma inside them?

Comment: Hmmm.  I'm seeing the problem differently now.  Your BLRG would basically become a tunnel of electromagnetic "traps."  At one end, you've got a large one to initialize things, then a series of smaller ones that rapidly turn on and off as the ball passes by, accelerating it at each step.  It gets you over the melting problem, but after that I don't know.

Comment: Thankfully, ball lighting usually travel without deterring from a horizontal line and can be manipulated with electromagnetic fields.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the fact that nobody fully understands how ball lightning is actually formed, you're likely to run into the same issues that impede the development of a regular directed lightning gun.  Lightning is extremely unpredictable and nearly impossible to direct unless you have the ability to significantly alter the electric potential of your *target*, at which point you might as well just use whatever mechanism you are using to alter their electric potential to damage them directly and forego the lightning gun altogether.

If ball lightning responds to magnetic fields, you have the same issue.  If it responds to air pressure, that's just as unpredictable - any attempt you used to alter the air pressure of your target would be influenced by the ambient air conditions, creating unpredictable vortices and causing your ball lightning to go careening out of control.  If you have enough control over the air pressure in the area to reliably send a ball lighting towards a target, there are much more efficient ways of inflicting damage than shooting ball lighting at them.

Comment: Directing lightning is fairly simple by using laser pulses to ionize air, which creates an extremely low-resistance path for a high-voltage discharge to follow. This sort of thing has been done for at least 20 years. Not sure why you are convinced that you need to somehow alter the target.

Answer (score 1):

The SHIVA STAR Project utilizing ultra-high energy capacitors experimented with this and eventually became the top-secret MARAUDER program and ceased reporting results. What you describe is actually a high energy plasma toroid weapon. Once the plasma toroid (ball lightning) impacts something it explodes violently releasing immense heat and a burst of x-rays and to a lesser degree gamma radiation and other electromagnetic effects capable of frying electronics. Its not very effecient in atmosphere though, plasma blooming means you need monumental power levels to project the plasma toroid even a short distance before atmospheric bloom causes the toroid to lose coherency. It would be an excellent space weapon though. 
Heres a link: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MARAUDER

Heres a photo of the capacitor bank they used in SHIVA STAR prior to going top secret: [image]

Answer (score 1):

Nobody knows how ball lightning works. I can tell you for sure that a railgun wouldnt be practical. Railguns require physical contact with the projectile,regardless of what the projectile is. That would melt the rails.
A coilgun does not need contact.
So off the top of my head, ionize air within the rifle, put current through the plasma, accelerate with coils, and then do something to form it into a ball without it immediately blooming into nothing after leaving the barrel. The last part is the issue. Nobody knows how to do this to the best of my knowledge as of 2023.
Something I have thought about that probably wouldn't work are virtual rails. A laser induced plasma channel conducts current through air in a straight line. What if those virtual rails behaved as a railgun and maintained the shape of the plasma as it's accelerated? The problem I keep coming back to is the Lorentz force will try to rip the rails apart, and being made of air means that wouldn't be too difficult. A lightning bolt gun that shoots 2 opposite polarity bolts to complete the circuit and a laser gun are both doable. I don't think what your asking will ever be practical without a lot of handwaving.
Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

## You have to ignore science

You're mostly there since your world ignores the energy requirements, like Ghostbusters packing nuclear proton packs into backpacks. Your gun simply won't pass the hard science test no matter what you do, so don't rely too much on explaining the tech in your railgun.

If you harnessed ball lighting in a weapon it would be a powerful tool indeed. In 1749, physicist and abbot Jean-Antoine Nollet was conducting an experiment with a Leyden jar when a ball of lightning struck him and killed him instantly. He was conducting the same experiment Benjamin Franklin is famous for today, capturing atmospheric static charge in the air in a leyden jar with his son. However, Franklin fortunately never had lightning strike; he just captured the atmospheric charge during a storm in a jar.

### Believable Ball Lightning

Hard science aside, you can improve the suspension of disbelief by briefly describing your weapon's operation, which will require the following components:

- An amazing insulator. Generally these are either ceramic or some advanced glass composition.
- A way to charge the air ahead of the ball. Electricity always follows the path of least resistance. Lightning is no exception: The crooked path lightning takes between earth and the cloud (lightning travels up, not down), has been ionized before the electricity arcs through it. The most reliable way is to shoot a very fine wire at your target. The lightning will follow the path to ground, vaporizing the wire along the way. Otherwise, shooting a small extremely hot pellet would slightly ionize the air in its wake. The pellet is not a bullet and it doesn't need lethal force. It only needs to reach the target to create a path of ionized air that will guide the ball lightning.

Let me repeat: This won't actually work, for the many reasons already discussed, not the least of which is the fact that we don't exactly know what ball lightning is. But you'll at least be able to suspend disbelief long enough to get your story told.

### The Weapon:

It should have a large disk or container on it, suggesting a leyden jar or capacitor. One of the best energy guns I have seen on film was the one created in *"The Darkest Hour"* [image: E-Gun from The Darkest Hour] (Copyright New Regency Productions).

The sound would be distinctive, as a slight "pop" will be heard a fraction of a second before the ball lightning releases with a thunderclap, then a static hiss is heard as the air is ionized with electricity. Here is a non-technical storyline description of the weapon's action:

"The assassin seemed panicked, and in rapid breaths raised his pistol at Drake, not comprehending the menacing weapon Drake had leveled at him. Its large ceramic disk, its squarish barrel covered in copper wires. His face contorted with rage he bellowed, "I warned you!"
Then before anyone had time to react, a terrifying electric shock filled the room. The distinctive pop of a ball lightning gun sounded and before anyone could scream an almighty thunderclap ripped through the air, which crackled with the static of billions of newly excited ions, leaving behind a smoldering cloud of charred ash settling into a pile pile where the assassin stood seconds ago.

Again. Avoid going too far into detail on the technology, it doesn't actually work.

Answer (score 0):

You might launch an apparatus out of your railgun that generates your ball lighnting mid-air, that would have the added bonus of the apparatus's kinetic energy plus the terrifying ball of electricity